# How to avoid confirmation interaction when deleting items in Red Hat Linux?

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux

I'm running Red Hat Linux and every time I remove something it ask me if I'm sure.

This is not a big deal but if I try to remove a sub directory with multiple subdirectories and hundreds of files in it, this can be very time consuming.

Is there a way to set Red Hat so that it will not ask for confirmation every time I try to delete something?

Comment: You mean `rm` or what

Answer (score 0):

@harrymc When I checked the alias, for "rm", it indicated

```
type rm 
rm is aliased to 'rm -i'
```

After clearing the alias, everything is good now.
Thanks